# Android Share text/link or image on facebook

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to share text/image or link on Facebook using intent and i want share only on Facebook.

share intent for mail working properly but not Facebook. please help

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps
                                     // should handle
                                    // this
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, AppLink);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow to share a link uing intent , you have to use Facebook sdk to do this 
visit [This link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

Answer (score 0):

Use facebook Sdk.

```
private void shareFacebook(){

   if (!ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) return;

        ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        ShareLinkContent.Builder builder = new    ShareLinkContent.Builder();
        builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("file sharing url"));
        builder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("image url));

        builder.setContentDescription("http://something.com");
        builder.setContentTitle("title / info");

        dialog.show(getActivity(), builder.build());
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.please_wait, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Don't forget to initialize facebook sdk on your activity / fragment.

Hope it help you.